# Excel - Unique lisit from 2 column array for selection

Tags: excel, unique, array-formulas

I have a DB table on a separate sheet locked and hidden from the users that lists facilities and their zones with multiple entries for some facility/zone pairings. When the primary search fails to return a match, I have a function that lets me specify the zone and returns all the facilities in that zone. The problem is that it displays all the duplicates as well. What I want to find is a way to show just the unique facilities in the selected zone. I don't want to have to touch the DB and filter every time I want to search by zone. All the other unique listings I find in the forums return all unique listings (1 column array) where I only want for a select group (2 column array).

Sample DB attached (Facility in A; Zone in B; Searched Zone in D1)

Array formula copied down to next few rows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($D$1=$B:$B,ROW($B:$B)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Returns 4, 5, 5
    - Desired 4, 5

[image: Sample DB w/ Search]

Comment: `...IF(($D$1=$B:$B)*(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,A:A)=0),...`

Comment: And change the `ROW(1:1)` to just `1`

Comment: One more note.  One should not use full column references in Array formulas.  Limit the references to that of the data set.  It will speed up the calculations.

Comment: I have the limited references in the live version. Also, the `Row(1:1)` allows the formula to be copied down without having to edit each line to 2, 3, etc.

Comment: I understand what the ROW(1:1) is doing I am saying with the added countif it is not needed. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIF() to find the unique values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($D$1=$B$2:$B$14)*(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$14)=0),ROW($B$2:$B$14)),1)),"")
```

Remember that this is an array formula that requires Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]